# Как сделать поиск по БД с помощью Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, ооп, entity-framework

Привет!Мне нужно сделать вывод с бд при помощи EF.Пользователь добавляет продукты которые есть у него в холодильнике по одному нажимая на кнопку "Добавить продукт",Эти продукты добавляются в массив  `List<string> productsList = new List<string>();`и я планирую перебирая этот массив выводить с бд рецепты в которых есть эти продукты.Но загвоздка в том что есть таблица с Продуктами и таблица с Рецептами и так как у одного продукта может быть много рецептов и в рецептаможет быть много продуктов я их связываю через третью таблицу RecipieIngredients в которой они связаны своими id.Проблема в том что я не могу понять как мне реализовать поиск рецептов по продуктам и потом вывести список рецептов?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ingredients

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Ingredients
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Ingredients()
        {
            this.RecipeIngredient = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Recipe

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Recipe
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Recipe()
        {
            this.RecipeIngredient = new HashSet<RecipeIngredient>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Prop_Time { get; set; }
        public string Instructions { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<RecipeIngredient> RecipeIngredient { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RecipeIngredient

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class RecipeIngredient
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int RecipeId { get; set; }
        public int IngredientId { get; set; }

        public virtual Ingredients Ingredients { get; set; }
        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы хорошо подумали на структурой класса рецепт? попробуйте полазить по сайтам с рецептами, посмотрите какие данные указывают в рецептах, те рецепты которые я видел в вашу структура вписать не получится. Ваш проект для изучения языка/платформы/прочее?

Answer (score 1):

вроде, sql бы выглядел так:

```
SELECT Name, Prop_Time, Instructions  
FROM Recipe  WHERE Id in 
( SELECT RecipeID  
  FROM RecipeIngredient  
  WHERE IngredientId = IDискомогоИнгридиента
)
```

соответственно бы Linq:

```
//структуры данных
DbSet<Ingredient> ingrs;
DbSet<Recipe> recs;
DbSet<RecipeIngredients> recIngrs;
//тогда
int[] ingrIDs = { 0, 1, 42, 100500 };//список ID_ингредиентов, имеющихся в холодрильнике
var recIDs = recIngrs.Where(ri => (ingrIDs.Contains(ri.IngredientId))).Select(ri => ri.Id);//ID рецептов с данными ингредиентами
var recs4ingr = recs.Where(r => (recIDs.Contains(r.Id))).Select(r => (new { r.Name, r.Prop_Time, r.Instructions}));//внятная информация по рецептам с данными ингредиентами
```

что-то наподобие, в общем  :)