# Как сделать поиск в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Привет!Мне нужно сделать выборку в таблице `Recipe` данных которые были введены в текстбокс `inputProduct` и с тех рецептов которые были выбраны взять значение `Prop_Time` и вывести его в `label4`.

```
private void AddProduct_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Db1Context context = new Db1Context();

            var label1 = new Label();
            var label2 = new Label();
            var label3 = new Label();
            var label4 = new Label();
            var label5 = new Label();
            i++;

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(label1);
            label1.Text = inputProduct.Text;
            flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(label2);
            label2.Text = inputGrams.Text;
            flowLayoutPanel3.Controls.Add(label3);
            flowLayoutPanel4.Controls.Add(label4);
            flowLayoutPanel5.Controls.Add(label5);
            label5.Text = Convert.ToString(i); 
        }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
P.S. В Prop_time хранится значение ккал/гр.

Comment: казалось бы , причём тут *время*...

Comment: см. табл. `Recipe` и что изменилось с [прошлого раза](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/801518/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%91%D0%94-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-entity-framework)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте через LINQ.

```
var lst=context.Recipe.Where(x=>x.RecipeField==inputProduct.Text).Select(x=>x.Prop_time).ToList();
```

После отработки запроса получите список интересующих вас записей в переменной `lst`.

Comment: Сделал.`'Recipe" не содержит определения для "RecipeField" и не удалось найти метод расширения "RecipeField", принимающий тип "Recipe" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).`
Вот так реализововал:
`label3.Text = context.Recipe.Where(x => x.RecipeField == inputProduct.Text).Select(x => x.Prop_time).ToList();`

Comment: @OleksandrTatarinov вместо "RecipeField" нужно выбрать нужное поле, по которому будет вестись отбор.